# VirtualBox - Guru Meditation

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server

I'm facing a problem with this scenario using latest versions of:

- **VirtualBox:** Version 6.1.6 r137129 (Qt5.6.2)
- **Host:** Windows 10 Home (Version 19035.1) (virtualization is enabled in the BIOS and Hyper-V is not installed as it's Windows 10 Home Edition)
- **Client:** Windows Server 2019 (Version 19624)

As soon as I run the VM for installation from ISO file  VirtualBox says:

[image]

*A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.*

*For help, please see the Community section on https://www.virtualbox.org or your support contract. Please provide the contents of the log file VBox.log and the image file VBox.png, which you can find in the C:\Users\franc\VirtualBox VMs\Windows Server_\Logs directory, as well as a description of what you were doing when this error happened.
Note that you can also access the above files by selecting Show Log from the Machine menu of the main VirtualBox window.*

*Press OK if you want to power off the machine or press Ignore if you want to leave it as is for debugging. Please note that debugging requires special knowledge and tools, so is recommended to press OK now.*

[image]

I allocated to the VM:

- 2 CPUs
- 80GB of Virtual HD
- 4096MB or RAM (I also tried to allocate 2048MB, same error)
- Chipset: PIIX3
- Enable I/O APIC
- Enable PAE/NX

In the logs VBox.log I see:

```
00:00:03.357707 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37
```

and:

```
00:00:12.148500 VCPU[0] APIC Local Vector Table (LVT):
00:00:12.148501 lvt     timermode  mask  trigger  rirr  polarity  dlvr_st  dlvr_mode   vector
00:00:12.148502 Timer    One-shot   1                               Idle                 0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148507 Thermal             1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148511 Perf                1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148514 LINT0               0     Edge      0   ActiveHi    Idle     ExtINT      0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148517 LINT1               0     Edge      0   ActiveHi    Idle     NMI         0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148541 Error               1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148545 VCPU[1] APIC Local Vector Table (LVT):
00:00:12.148546 lvt     timermode  mask  trigger  rirr  polarity  dlvr_st  dlvr_mode   vector
00:00:12.148547 Timer    One-shot   1                               Idle                 0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148549 Thermal             1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148552 Perf                1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148554 LINT0               1     Edge      0   ActiveHi    Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148556 LINT1               1     Edge      0   ActiveHi    Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
00:00:12.148558 Error               1                               Idle     Fixed       0 (0x0)
```

While in VBoxHardening.log:

```
42e4.2024: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: error opening 'C:\Windows\System32\edgegdi.dll': 0 (NtPath=\??\C:\Windows\System32\edgegdi.dll; Input=edgegdi.dll; rcNtGetDll=0xc0000135
```

and:

```
42e4.2024: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: error opening 'C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll': 0 (NtPath=\??\C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll; Input=C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll; rcNtGetDll=0x0
```

..and, yes, Windows Defender is OFF.

Comment: Did you try enabling VT-x (enable 64-bit Virtual machines)?  I would try this first.

Comment: You chose 40MB VGA output for video. Are you able to increase that?

Comment: "VBoxVGA: Use this graphics controller for legacy guest OSes. This is the default graphics controller for Windows versions before Windows 7 and for Oracle Solaris". "VBoxSVGA: The default graphics controller for new VMs that use Windows 7 or later.". Change it to SVGA and try again.

Comment: @spikey_richie, thank you but is failing with VBoxSVGA too. I also increased it to 80MB

Comment: @John, VT-x is enabled in the BIOS

Comment: I looked at the VB spec's and could not find anything about Server 2019. You might consider a different virtualizing application as a test (trial version).  VMware or Hyper-V

Comment: Thank you @John, I will try and I will let you know

Comment: @John, I think you nailed it: Windows Server 2016 can load from ISO. Post it as an answer and I will label it as the good answer

Comment: Thank you.  I posted an answer for you to consider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the VB spec's and could not find anything about Server 2019. You might consider a different virtualizing application as a test (trial version). VMware or Hyper-V.

Virtual Box supports Server 2016, but Server 2019 is much newer.

Comment: FYI: 2016 arrived to the installation but then was freezing. But that was a problem not related to my main question. 2012 is installed and I'm working on it. Overall I think VirtualBox doesn't work well with latest ISO.